# "No Google Analytics tracking code found" error when trying to use Google Experiments

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I am 100% sure that I have installed the Google Analytics tracking code successfully because when I visit the site where I installed it, I can see my visit as an online active user in the "REAL-TIME" section.

I am trying to use Google Experiments for split testing. I go to the "Experiments" section in Google Analytics:

[image]

I am configuring a new experiment and in the last step, when I try to validate my configuration by using the "Experiment Code Validation" option, I see this error: **"No Google Analytics tracking code found."**

The help Google provides, or hint to fix this error is: "Install Google Analytics tracking code on your experiment pages, then check them again.
We scan only the first 256KB of a page looking for scripts. If your code appears after the first 256KB, you see this error." My Google Analytics tracking code appears immediately after the `<head>` line in my code. Also, Google Analytics reports have been working correctly for me for months, reporting traffic and visits to my site. I do not understand why I get this "No Google Analytics tracking code found" error. See the error in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side this:

> A name and URL is required for each variation but you can use any
>   value you want for the URL of the variation since it is not applicable
>   for this type of implementation... The URL is required but not
>   applicable or used for this type of implementation... Note: Because
>   URLs are not applicable to this implementation but are required to
>   configure an experiment you can ignore any errors or notifications
>   such as "We could not find the URL you entered".

I simply ignored that error and moved on with my tests.